# Libevent: get list of accepted connections

Tags: c, linux, libevent

I'm working on a multi-threaded client-server application designed for usage in the enterprise internal network. I use **libevent** for asynchronous I/O (several pthreads with one  evconnlistener/bufferevent object per thread) and **OpenSSL** for cryptography.

Now I need to determine mechanism of monitoring of the established connections (for example, check on the server side if client got down or exceeds some timeouts). And it seems like libevent 2.0.21 does not provide any API to get list of active connections.

I am ready to write global data structure (list of client IP's for instance), but may be there is a method for this purposes, hidden deep inside libevent API?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can peruse libevent source code, it is small enough.

Comment: Libevent usually timeout immediately if there is a disconnect on the client side. The time differential between client disconnect and the event callback is less than a second. This is my event_cb below.
bufferevent_setcb(bev, read_cb, write_cb, event_cb, NULL);
So what I am saying is that checking the status is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it's nessesary for me to determine the parameters of socket (IP and port) accepted in accept_cb(). Perhaps I will try rewrite several functions and recompile library.

Comment: @MickeyKawick, Yes, you are right. I suggest check the [code](https://github.com/jasonish/libevent-examples/blob/master/buffered-echo-server/libevent_echosrv_buffered.c) provided by [Jason Ish](https://github.com/jasonish), then use the client to save the socket information, and check when socket closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is no way to list the objects watched by an event base, let alone list only the established connections and their status. You could try to patch libevent for your needs, or you can keep score out of the connections accepted outside of libevent.

Comment: I think this [code] (https://github.com/jasonish/libevent-examples/blob/master/buffered-echo-server/libevent_echosrv_buffered.c) and do it. When accept, add the socket into global variable, and when close, remove the socket from the global variable.